# Send Broadcast/service issue in above Android 4.2

Tags: android, broadcast

I have two application. one application has receiver. While trying to send broadcast from second application it is showing following error.

```
02-06 16:18:03.045: E/DatabaseUtils(2847): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
02-06 16:18:03.045: E/DatabaseUtils(2847):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:13682)
02-06 16:18:03.045: E/DatabaseUtils(2847):  at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2250)
```

This is happening in above 4.2 only. In 4.2 its working fine.

Comment: check if your receiver is mentioned in the manifest files

Comment: or trying add a " --user 0" for the "am broadcast" command to work.